# Relacionamento Muitos para Muitos Laravel - For each Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estou começando no Laravel.
Estou com seguinte problema.
Tenho três tabelas com relacionamento N:N.

- ctrl_cm_tecnicos
- ctrl_lista_tecnicos
- acl_lista_tecnicos

As tabelas se relacionam da seguinte maneira.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um Controller Chamado ListagemTecnicosController, que estou enviando os dados para minha index.
Já testei o relacionamento entre ctrl_lista_tecnicos e ctrl_cm_tecnicos atraves do dd($this->objTecnico->find(664)->RelCms), e o relacionamento ocorre perfeitamente.

```
    class ListagemTecnicosController extends Controller
{
    private $objTecnico;
    private $objCm;
    private $objAcl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->objTecnico = new CtrlListaTecnico();
        $this->objCm = new CtrlCmTecnico();
        $this->objAcl = new AclCmTecnico();
        
    }   

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        

        //dd($this->objCm->find(62)->RelTecnicos);
        //dd($this->objTecnico->find(664)->RelCms);

        $tecnicos=$this->objTecnico->all();
        $cm=$this->objCm->all();
        return view('index', compact('tecnicos', 'cm'));

    }
```

Porem quando chego no meu index, não sei como exibir Regional que esta na tabela ctrl_cm_tecnicos.

```
 <div class="col-12 m-auto">         
          <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Rg</th>
                <th scope="col">CPF</th>
                <th scope="col">Regional</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                @foreach ($tecnicos as $t)
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{$t['id']}}</th>
                            <td>{{$t['nome']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$t['rg']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$t['cpf']}}</td>
                            <td>{{'Regional'}}</td>
                            
                        </tr>
                @endforeach
              
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

A exibição dos demais dados estão corretas, conforme tela abaixo, falta somente a regional que é o cm da tabela -> ctrl_cm_tecnicos.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ?
Estou a mais de um dia pesquisando uma solução mas não encontrei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mas, quem é regional na sua tabela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudei a abordagem e criei uma query no controler através do metodo DB::table ListagemTecnicosController para exibir os dados que eu gostaria que é o campo cm da tabela ctrl_cm_tecnicos.cm.
Não sei se foi a maneira mais correta de fazer, mas deu certo.

```
 $tecnicos = DB::table('ctrl_lista_tecnicos')
        ->join('acl_cm_tecnicos', 'acl_cm_tecnicos.id_tecnicos', '=', 'ctrl_lista_tecnicos.id')
        ->join('ctrl_cm_tecnicos', 'ctrl_cm_tecnicos.id', '=', 'acl_cm_tecnicos.id_cms')
        ->select('ctrl_lista_tecnicos.*', 'ctrl_cm_tecnicos.cm')
        ->get();
   


    return view('index', ['tecnicos' => $tecnicos]);
```

No index.blade ficou dessa maneira.

```
 @foreach ($tecnicos as $t)
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{$t->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$t->nome}}</td>
                        <td>{{$t->rg}}</td>
                        <td>{{$t->cpf}}</td>
                        <td>{{$t->cm}}</td>
                    </tr>
            @endforeach
```

E por fim consegui exibir o campo cm da tabela ctrl_cm_tecnicos.cm .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode marcar usa própria resposta como a correta, para quem navegar nesta questão compreender que está é uma solução para o problema